# StackPanel space between each item at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

Ok I have a stack panel and I add child at runtime like so

```
UserC.ShowData sD = new UserC.ShowData();
ShowDataStackPanel.Children.Add(sD);
```

I know I can define the margin if I add the item before the runtime but I,ve looked and it's not very clear how to add a user control with a margin at runtime.

***Edit***

The stackpanel is defined like so

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ShowDataStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="727,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="617" Width="247"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Margin propriety for the sD control :

```
sD.Margin = new Thickness(12,12,0,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Margin property:

```
UserC.ShowData sD = new UserC.ShowData();
ShowDataStackPanel.Children.Add(sD);
sD.Margin = new Thickness(727,33,0,0);
```